# How to check radio button if input is focused

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I focus the `input` element it will
automatically check the radio button. The two buttons are doing fine however when I'm trying to focus on input field, the radio button is not checked at all. How do i solve this problem?

Here are my codes :

```css
.rdo + label.lbl-rdo.noah-forms-lbl.nf-opt-lbl:before {
    top: 28px;
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo:hover:before, .nk .col .chk + .lbl-chk:hover:before {
    border-color: #2575c4;
}
.rdo:checked + .lbl-rdo:before, .nk .col .chk:checked + .lbl-chk:before {
    border-color: #2575c4;
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo:before, .nk .col .chk + .lbl-chk:before {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 7px;
    top: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #7a8a9a;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo:before, .nk .col .rdo + .lbl-rdo:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo:before, .rdo + .lbl-rdo:after, .chk + .lbl-chk:before, .chk + .lbl-chk:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: .14s ease transform;
    -moz-transition: .14s ease transform;
    transition: .14s ease transform;
}


.rdo:checked + .lbl-rdo.noah-forms-lbl.nf-opt-lbl:after {
    background-color: #2575c4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo.noah-forms-lbl.nf-opt-lbl:after {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 13px;
    top: 34px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}
.rdo:checked + .lbl-rdo:after {
    background-color: #2575c4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo:after {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 11px;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo:before, .rdo + .lbl-rdo:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.rdo + .lbl-rdo:before, .rdo + .lbl-rdo:after, .chk + .lbl-chk:before, .chk + .lbl-chk:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: .14s ease transform;
    -moz-transition: .14s ease transform;
    transition: .14s ease transform;
}

.nf-input-opt {
    padding-left: 29px;
}

.nf-aImage-c, .nf-close-c {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rdo-wrapper fullwidth">
                    <input id="rdo21" type="radio" name="sample4" class="rdo">
                    <label class="lbl-rdo fullwidth noah-forms-lbl nf-opt-lbl" for="rdo21">
                        <div class="col col-12">
                            <div class="nf-opt-c">
                                <div class="nf-input-opt">
                                    <input type="text" name="" class="txtbox" value="Option 1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="nf-aImage-c">
                                    <div class="nf-opt-icon _nf-aImage-opt"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nf-close-c">
                                    <div class="nf-opt-icon _nf-close-opt"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use something like this:

```
$("label.lbl-rdo input").focus(function() {
  $(this).closest("label.lbl-rdo").trigger("click")
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("label.lbl-rdo input").focus(function() {
  $(this).closest("label.lbl-rdo").trigger("click")
})
```

```css
.rdo+label.lbl-rdo.noah-forms-lbl.nf-opt-lbl:before {
  top: 28px;
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo:hover:before,
.nk .col .chk+.lbl-chk:hover:before {
  border-color: #2575c4;
}

.rdo:checked+.lbl-rdo:before,
.nk .col .chk:checked+.lbl-chk:before {
  border-color: #2575c4;
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo:before,
.nk .col .chk+.lbl-chk:before {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 7px;
  top: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #7a8a9a;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo:before,
.nk .col .rdo+.lbl-rdo:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo:before,
.rdo+.lbl-rdo:after,
.chk+.lbl-chk:before,
.chk+.lbl-chk:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .14s ease transform;
  -moz-transition: .14s ease transform;
  transition: .14s ease transform;
}

.rdo:checked+.lbl-rdo.noah-forms-lbl.nf-opt-lbl:after {
  background-color: #2575c4;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo.noah-forms-lbl.nf-opt-lbl:after {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 13px;
  top: 34px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.rdo:checked+.lbl-rdo:after {
  background-color: #2575c4;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo:after {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 11px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo:before,
.rdo+.lbl-rdo:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.rdo+.lbl-rdo:before,
.rdo+.lbl-rdo:after,
.chk+.lbl-chk:before,
.chk+.lbl-chk:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .14s ease transform;
  -moz-transition: .14s ease transform;
  transition: .14s ease transform;
}

.nf-input-opt {
  padding-left: 29px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rdo-wrapper fullwidth">
  <input id="rdo21" type="radio" name="sample4" class="rdo">
  <label class="lbl-rdo fullwidth noah-forms-lbl nf-opt-lbl" for="rdo21">
      <div class="col col-12">
          <div class="nf-opt-c">
              <div class="nf-input-opt">
                  <input type="text" name="" class="txtbox" value="Option 1">
              </div>
              <div class="nf-aImage-c">
                  <div class="nf-opt-icon _nf-aImage-opt"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="nf-close-c">
                  <div class="nf-opt-icon _nf-close-opt"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </label>
</div>
```